# Использование стека в функции(изменение структуры по указателю на структуру) СИ

Tags: c, структуры, стек

Имеется код следующего вида, каким образом будет использоваться стек при вызове функции **init_function**? В стеке будет выделено место под указатель **Data** - это само собой, но будет ли копироваться вся глобальная структура в стек при изменении полей структуры? И на сколько правильно возвращать из функции локальный указатель указывающий на глобальную структуру, каково время жизни этого локального указателя?

```
typedef struct {
 int a;
 int b;
 int c;
} Struct_t;

Struct_t Struct;

Struct_t *init_function(void) {
 Struct_t *Data = &Struct;
 Data->a = 0x23;
 Data->b = 0x7F;
 Data->c = 0x1;
 return(Data);
}

int main(void) {
 Struct_t *init = init_function();
 //Do some...
}
```

Comment: "В стеке будет выделено место под указатель Data" - не факт. оптимизатор может и обойтись... И уж точно незачем копировать в стек `Struct`. Ну, а возвращенный указатель на глобальную переменную имеет ту же продолжительность жизни, что и сама глобальная переменная...

Comment: На счет указателя на глобальную переменную - это я погорячился, ответ очевиден ).  А тогда в чем разница, если изменить функцию, таким образом?    `Struct_t *init_function(void) {
     Struct.a = 0x23;
     Struct.b = 0x7F;
     Struct.c = 0x1;
     return(&Struct.);
    }`

Comment: Да ни в чем, по сути...

Comment: Спасибо. Просто я считал, что в первом варианте, будет однозначно использоваться стек(будет ли копироваться вся структура не в курсе), а во втором мы исключаем использование стека.

Comment: Умный оптимизатор будет сразу работать с глобальным объектом, а его адрес сразу поместит в переменную `init`, ничего не создавая в стеке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Коротко - листайте вниз до "Отвечаем на ваши вопросы" .

Подробно - смотрите сюда.

Будем ориентироваться на мою "машину", поэтому вот короткие сведения после команды `uname -a`:

```
Linux ... amd64 ... x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Покажу asm-код `init_function` и `main` при компилировании без оптимизации (всё отформатировано, чтобы вы видели только суть).

```
;No Optim.
init_function:

push   rbp
mov    rbp,rsp

lea rax,[rip+0x200a2b]      ; переместили адрес глобальной переменной "Struct" в rax 
mov QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax ; с ячейки по адресу ( rbp - 8 ) записали адрес глобальной струтуры
                            ; это и есть "Struct_t *Data = &Struct;"
mov rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8] ; переместили адрес структуры в rax 
mov DWORD PTR [rax],0x23    ; Data->a = 0x23;
mov rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8] ; переместили адрес структуры в rax  
mov DWORD PTR [rax+0x4],0x7f; Data->b = 0x7f;
mov rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8] ; переместили адрес структуры в rax 
mov DWORD PTR [rax+0x8],0x1 ; Data->c = 0x1;
mov rax,QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8] ; подготовка к возвращению в main : заносим в rax адрес глобальной структуры;

pop rbp
ret
```

Согласитесь, что создание локальной переменной `Struct_t *Data` здесь - это бессмысленно?
Компилятор, этого к сожалению не понимает.

Пробегитесь по `main`, это вам понадобится чуть позже.

```
;No Optim.
main:    
push rbp                                                                                               
mov rbp,rsp

sub rsp,0x10 ; Struct_t *init;
call init_function ; теперь в rax адрес изменённой структуры
mov QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax ; теперь в init этот адрес

mov    eax,0x0
leave
ret
```

А что, если откомпилировать с флагом "O1"?

```
;O1 Optim.
init_function:
   ; тут уже нету работы со стековым кадром
   ; сразу, ничего никуда не пихая, меняем содержимое напрямую
mov DWORD PTR [rip+0x200a2c],0x23 ;Data->a = 0x23;
mov DWORD PTR [rip+0x200a26],0x7f ;Data->b = 0x7f;
mov DWORD PTR [rip+0x200a20],0x1  ;Data->c = 0x1;
lea rax,[rip+0x200a11]            ;подготовка к возвращению в main : заносим в rax адрес глобальной структуры;
ret
```

Собственно, локальной переменной уже не создаётся, но всё ещё возвращается изменённая структура. Почему? Да потому что ей нужно в любом случае что-то вернуть, на сигнатуру функции посмотрите :)

Однако, в `main` компилятор посчитал переменную `Struct_t *init` ненужной, потому что вы с ней всё равно ничего не делали :)

(это без "DoSome". Если бы вы с ней что-то делали, то она бы сохранилась, а иначе ей здесь незачем быть)

```
main:
call init_function; вызвали функцию
mov eax,0x0 ; код завершения
ret ; закончили
```

> Если `init_function` не создаёт локальные переменные, а `main`
>   <s>тупо</s> просто вызывает функцию , то почему бы вообще не исключить
>   переходы в эту функцию?

Это моё предположение о том, как "думает" компилятор с "02"-оптимизацией.

Если в "main" ключевая команда была `call init_function`, то теперь, после "O2" она выглядит вот так :

```
;O2 Optim.
main:
mov rax,0x7f00000023
mov DWORD PTR [rip+0x200b34],0x1                         
mov QWORD PTR [rip+0x200b25],rax 
xor eax,eax ; даже перемещение нуля в код завершения 
            ; было оптимизировано :)
ret
```

А вот с комментариями :

```
;O2 Optim.
main:
mov rax,0x7f00000023 ; чуть ниже поясню, зачем так
mov DWORD PTR [rip+0x200b34],0x1 ; Data->c = 0x1;                          
mov QWORD PTR [rip+0x200b25],rax ; начиная с ячейки по адресу,где находится 
                                 ; адрес начала глобальной структуры, записать 
                                 ; т.н "четверное слово" 
                                 ; (машинное слово, чаще всего - это 2 байта). 

; Пояснение :
; Допустим, что все поля структуры у вас зануляются и все int по 4 байта:
; тогда память вашей инициализированной структуры будет вот такой:
; 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00 | 00 00 00 00

; rax - это регистр размером 8 байт : 00 00 00 7f | 00 00 00 23
; нашей командой впихнём байты rax с адреса, где начинается структура, 
; то есть буквально сюда : -> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 <- 00 00 00 01)
; переместив в них значение rax, получим следующее :
; 00 00 00 23 | 00 00 00 7f | 00 00 00 01 |
;    int a    |    int b    |     int c   |

xor eax,eax
ret
```

С **03** будет то же самое.

Подведём итоги для вашего случая ( и моей "машины" :D ):

- Без оптимизаций локальная переменная "**создаётся**", но поскольку это
  указатель, то она будет просто иметь тот же адрес, что и ваша
  глобальная структура.
- С оптимизацией "**01**" у вас не будет создаваться локальной переменной
  `Data` ( как и `init` в `main`, но причина другая ), но полученную
  изменённую структуру вы будете возвращать, ибо тип, который
  возвращает функция - `Struct_t`.
- С оптимизацией "**02**" (или "**03**") всё будет выполняться в
  `main`, да ещё и хитрым образом инициализирует сразу два поля для
  вашей структуры.

### Отвечаем на ваши вопросы

> Каким образом будет использоваться стек при вызове функции
>   `init_function`?

В зависимости от оптимизации, которую вы выберете.

> В стеке будет выделено место под указатель Data - это само собой...

Вы это написали, потому что в этом сомневаетесь, поэтому это всё равно, что вопрос. При компилировании **без оптимизации** и **в нашем случае**- да, так и будет.

> Будет ли копироваться вся глобальная структура в стек при изменении
>   полей структуры?

Поскольку у вас структура инициализирована глобально, то компилятору незачем создавать её копию, чтобы её поменять. <s>Что за вопросы, молодой человек?! :D</s>

> Насколько правильно возвращать из функции локальный указатель,
>   указывающий на глобальную структуру.

Мало того, что создавать глобальные переменные - это [не очень хорошая практика](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176118/when-is-it-ok-to-use-a-global-variable-in-c), так вы ещё и делаете бессмысленную "возню". Хотите изменить глобальную переменную - создайте ту же функцию, которая возвращает void, не создавайте локальных переменных, и меняйте структуру напрямую.

```
void init_function( void ) 
{
 Struct.a = 0x23;
 Struct.b = 0x7F;
 Struct.c = 0x1;
}
```

> Каково время жизни локального указателя `Data`?

Грубо говоря, время жизни любой локальной переменной = время жизни функции.

Локальная переменная перестаёт быть доступна уже тогда, когда идёт "демонтирование" стекового кадра (это почти в конце, но на уровне C-синтаксиса - это то, что делается до "return" ), если ,конечно, он есть :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо за такой развернутый ответ, смысл глобальной переменной в том, что она используется в обработчике прерывания, да и к тому же есть массив условных Struct, и использование указателя банально удобно для перехода на следующую структуру в обработчике прерывания. В условном мейне(а точнее в одной из задач РТОСа ) возвращаемый функцией указатель используется, потому оптимизации с выброшенной переменной и "мейна" естественно не будет. Использую оптимизацию -Ofast(По моему аналог O2)

Comment: Относительно вреда глобальной переменной: Именно для того, что бы ограничить видимость глобальной переменной используется возврат адреса на структуру. И этот адрес используется лишь в файле периферийного модуля.

Comment: Спасибо вам за отклик. Информация по fast-оптимизации тут gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html (там 03 + ещё парочка "плюшек"). Если вы считаете, что я ответил на ваш вопрос, то пометьте его правильным, пожалуйста)

Comment: Отметил, для добавления репутации, у самого не хватает репутации :) Компилятор не совсем GCC, у меня clang. Но основа поже, что GCC

Comment: @Oem , я не клянчил у вас репутацию. У нас просто половина правильных ответов остаются без "галки", и только потому, что некоторые посмотрят, сделают себе то, что надо, и забудут. Если у вас остались какие-то замечания или вопросы - говорите. Иначе у меня параноя, что я не удовлетворил вас в плане ответа. Мда уж, про c-lang надо было уточнить :)

Comment: Я сам хотел повысить Вам репутацию, так как ответ шикарен и полностью перекрыл все мои вопросы и даже более...

Comment: @Oem, что ж, тогда благодарю, что избавили меня от страданий :D